# Finding covariance using $E[X]$ and $E[Y]$

Tags: statistics, random-variables, covariance

I have a table

[image: table]

where I have found $E[X] = 2.6$ and $E[Y] = 2.44$.

\begin{align*}
E[X] &= 2 \times 0.4 + 3 \times 0.6 = 2.6 \\
E[Y] &= 2 \times 0.56 + 3 \times 0.44 = 2.44
\end{align*}

I have tried:

$$ Cov[X,Y] = E[XY] - E[X] E[Y]$$

How do I solve for covariance between $X$ and $Y$?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort. This should be added to the question rather than in the comments.

Comment: Thanks. Added information along with formula I have tried, but gone wrong with.

Comment: You cannot determine $Cov[X,Y]$ only by knowing $E[X]$ and $E[Y]$. You have to know certain knowledge on the *joint distribution* on $X$ and $Y$, and as such, covariance provides a useful insight on their joint distribution which cannot be glimpsed from the respective (marginal) distributions of $X$ and $Y$. To see how one actually computes $E[XY]$ out of the table, you may want to see Ahmad Bazzi's answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Using the formula you shared

$$Cov[X,Y] = E[X*Y] - E[X] * E[Y]$$

you have computed both $E(X),E(Y)$ . Now to compute $E(XY)$ treat $XY$ as a single random variable, ie the outcomes are $2\times 3=6$, $2\times 2=4 $ and $3\times 3 =9$. Get their respective probabilies from the table and compute the average as you did.